# Keras how to reshape MNIST images after dimensionality reduction

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mnist

I have been running a keras sequential model on mnist, and the first layer is as follows:

```
model.add(Reshape((28, 28, 1), input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
model.add(Conv2D(4, (2, 2), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(8, (2, 2), activation='relu'))
...
```

Where X_train.shape[1] = 784, which neatly reshapes into 28x28x1.
My problem is that now I am performing dimensionality reduction algorithms on the dataset, and there might end up only being some 228 columns afterwords. It can no longer be reshaped into 28x28x1. and in fact does not cleanly square at all. What am i supposed to do here to run this data though the neural network. Would I be losing out on something major by using flattened data? What does it take to throw in 228 columns instead of this?

Comment: You will always lose a bit of variance when performing dimensionality reduction.

Comment: What algorithm are you using for this?

Comment: @yudhiesh PCA for dimensionality reduction. I'm left with 228 columns transformed from 784. What does an input layer for this look like for keras since I can no longer reshape it to the actual image shape?

Comment: Just a question to make sure you are in a right way: Conv layers are good because the input data has spatial information in it. I don't know a lot about PCA but after using it, does the output of PCA has spatial information?

Comment: Could you try ```input_img = Input(shape=(784,))``` and use it like so ```Dense(128, activation='relu')(input_img)```? I do not think you need to use reshape.

Comment: @amin PCA keeps most of the information in an image. So you will still have spatial information. You can try using the MNIST dataset and visualising the images before and after using PCA. They will look almost identical but the after will be slightly less sharp.